# Active remote sensing to measure temperature?

Tags: sensor

I understand that objects give off EM emissions according to their temperature. But let's say this object is too far away to be measured via passive remote sensing. How can you measure the temperature of this object via active remote sensing? Surely you'd just be measuring the reflected EM emission wavelength and not the emitted wavelength of the object?

Comment: Unless this object has special properties that link its temperature to its electromagnetic reflectivity, it's not possible. One can, of course, build rather simple devices that would work very well for this kind of remote temperature sensing. Imagine a resonant bimetal antenna that changes its resonance frequency. I am sure such designs have been used before and they may even be commercially available. Temperature dependent paints will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this object has special properties that link its temperature to its electromagnetic reflectivity, it's not possible. One can, of course, build rather simple devices that would work very well for this kind of remote temperature sensing. Imagine a resonant bimetal antenna that changes its resonance frequency. I am sure such designs have been used before and they may even be commercially available. Temperature dependent paints will also work. That effect is called thermochromism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermochromism.